# Hashing and Encrypting JWT Token

Tags: security, encryption, token, jwt

I went through different post here, I am now more confused about how to implement security for tokens. . I currently implemented an authentication serivce (MVC4 + webAPIs) and a relying party (MVC4 app). Relying party (RP) redirects client to Authentication service (AS). AS creates a token, gives it to client. Client gives it to RP. RP adds more claims etc.
THis is what I want to do for securing the token:
HashingToken the token using HMAC SHA 256. How can I share the key between AS and RP? Do I have to sign it and add it in the payload and encrypt?

- I want to encrypt the token using AES/Rijndael algorithm/. Again how
  can I share the key with RP?
- RP will decrypt the token first and decode it with the Algorithm
  specified using the key shared to access the payload (timestamp,
  audience, issues etc).
- I am sliding the token expiry date. there is a field jit which needs
  to be unique to avoid replay attacks.. I am currently filling it with
  GUID.. I am not sure how to validate/use it in RP

I am currently sharing symmetric keys for hashing & encryption between AS and RP.

I am working on security for the first time.. although I have gone through multiple posts, I am yet to completely understand, and little confused after reading many posts. If someone can help..